# Reliability in WCF Polling Duplex Binding

Tags: wcf, silverlight, duplex, pollingduplexhttpbinding

I have a WCF Polling Duplex Service for silverlight clients. I wanted to add Reliability to the service but first I got this error.

> The message version of the outgoing message (Soap11
>   (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/) AddressingNone
>   (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none)) does not
>   match that of the encoder (Soap12
>   (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope) Addressing10
>   (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing)). Make sure the binding is
>   configured with the same version as the message.

I changed the config files and I'm now getting the error below. Is reliability supported in WCF Polling Duplex?

> Unrecognized element 'reliableSession' in service reference
>   configuration. Note that only a subset of the Windows Communication
>   Foundation configuration functionality is available in Silverlight.

Comment: I think your question title basically provides a clue to the answer.

Comment: you mean the word "duplex" ?

Comment: Kind of. The WCF duplex bindings are hardly ever reliable in my experience.

Comment: well it's not too late for me to switch the binding to tcp but as far as I understand silverlight is the bottleneck here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem isn't the usage of WCF polling duplex, but Silverlight in general. It supports only a subset of WCF and according to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc896571%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) reliable sessions are not supported. A quotation:

"More advanced bindings and binding elements, such as the ones dealing with queues, **reliable sessions**, transactions, message-level security (such as WS-Security), peer-to-peer messaging, and transports other than HTTP, HTTPS, and TCP are not provided in Silverlight 4."